# ICS and support for gamepad/controller devices

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, usb-peripherals, game-controllers

I own an Asus Transformer TF101 and finally the official upgrade to ICS has been released.

I remember some ICS video previews where they said that ICS would have native support for gamepad/controllers and I have some questions about it:

- How can I understand if a market available USB gamepad is compatible with ICS?
- Is there a list of already supported devices?
- I also own a Microsoft PC Wireless controller, do you know if there is a driver written for ICS that supports that dongle?

Answer (score 1):

USB controllers [follow a spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) which means any USB controller "should" work. So there is not a "list of supported devices" as they all are supposed to work as long as they are not proprietary. Even an Xbox 360 wired controller should work (not sure about a wireless 360 controller, even when plugged in with the charge kit). Now your wireless controller is probably a different story. This is probably using some proprietary protocol to communicate information from the dongle to the controller, but you could try it. As long as the android device thinks that the dongle is a USB controller, and the dongle handles the communications to the controller, it may work.