# Using a USB game controller on Android

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, game-controllers

I have recently acquired a USB gamepad. It has two analog buttons, four L+R buttons, but is not a Playstation joystick -- it is recognized as a "Human iterface device"  on Windows 7.

Is there a way to make it work on ICS? I have a 4.0.2 Android tablet with a USB port and I can use a mouse or keyboard by just plugging it in, no other action needed. However the same doesn't happen when I plug my joypad.

According to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20009/ics-and-support-for-gamepad-controller-devices), "USB controllers follow a spec, any USB controller is supposed to work as long as it's not proprietary". My controller is generic (costed $20 and was recognized by windows without the need for a driver), but when I connect it on my tablet and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscontroller&hl=en)?

Comment: @ruda You won't see anything visible happen when you plug it in, have you tried using it in any games that have gamepad support?

Comment: @Sid - Yes, but my controller is just *a generic gamepad that happens to visually resemble a PS2 controller*, with analog buttons and all, so a sixaxis app won't help much, I suppose. Haven't tried, might try when I get home.

Comment: @GAThrawn I have tried using this app to check if the gamepad is working. Never heard of the app and picked it randomly, maybe the app is useless? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.killig.gamepadime